# get the array generated in - (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundArray:(NSArray *)array to viewdidload

Tags: iphone, json

I want to call the parser: method in viewdidload to get the array that i m getting in the method given below. I want to display it in the table. Please help as to how should i call the 
- (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundArray:(NSArray *)array in viewdidload.

Here is my code for the parser method.

```
- (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSLog(@"Array:%@",array);

    NSMutableArray *creditCards = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *user in array) {
        [creditCards addObject:[user objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",creditCards);
    self.list=creditCards;

    //Process array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can save each array that we recieve from `- (void)parser:(SBJsonStreamParser *)parser foundArray:(NSArray *)array` and can reload view after every array.

The problem is that `[tableView reload]` is not working properly, i.e. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`-delegate is not getting called.